# Sudden reputation loss

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting, reputation-history

I have lost over `~240` reputation all of a sudden. While, referring to the *Help Center > Moderation & Reputation*  section it clearly states that if the system detects unusual voting behavior over a **short period of time** it or the moderators perform corrections:

> Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "voting corrected"?
>   When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them. This could happen for a variety of reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge. No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targeted voting is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.
>
> ***If such a voting pattern continues to happen between two users mutually or from one user towards another, or otherwise falls outside of normal voting patterns, moderators and/or developers may investigate the matter; intentionally voting merely to reduce or inflate another user's reputation is considered abuse.***
>
> [continued]
>
> Such votes will generally be invalidated as part of an automated process that runs every day, but may also be invalidated manually by the staff after an investigation. When the votes are invalidated, the reputation gain or loss from the votes is undone, which results in a record in the recipient's reputation history labelled "voting corrected".

If you have a look at [my reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4373584/ahmad-baktash-hayeri?tab=reputation), the vote-ups/vote-downs have been issued at what I think is a fair distance in time between most of them although I would really like to know how the **pattern** for irregular voting defines such behavior.

[image]

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might be that most of the votes that got invalidated came from one other user. If that’s the case, in what you cited from the *Help Center > Moderation & Reputation* section, the relevant parts of it would be *If such a voting pattern continues to happen between two users mutually or from one user towards another, or otherwise falls outside of normal voting patterns* and *may also be invalidated manually by the staff after an investigation* — and if so, the “distance in time between most of them” doesn’t matter.

Comment: What does it matter? The system detected irregular voting patterns and removed them. Telling people exactly what those patterns are would defeat the purpose of the script, as it would allow malicious users to know exactly how long they have to wait before their votes will be recognized as fraudulent.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I didn't mean to know exactly the logic for the pattern either. All I wanted to know was the reason I lost that much of reputation, and it seems sideshowbarker might be correct.

Comment: Such big rep loss due to vote corrections or account deletions happen only rarely. If you are one of the false players, then you are lucky - you could have got a long suspension term, too. Don't worry - such big losses are really rare. I am so curious, how many times the mods checked my votes (both the ones I gave, and the ones I got), to check maybe also I am a gray player. But they didn't find anything :-) It is one of the last good things in the SE, they don't suspend without a strong reason. (Although they are often unfair in other sense.)

Answer (score 28):

In response to flags, I noticed a huge amount of vote inflation on a number of questions and answers. I traced this voting to a ring of people who appeared to be voting largely or entirely for one another. All of these people appear to be at the same location.

As a result, I requested an investigation of these votes by the community team. They found active voting coordination between over a dozen people at your location, and the votes going the various ways between you were invalidated. These votes were clearly not based on the content you posted, but were an attempt to artificially inflate the vote counts and reputation of everyone involved.

There were so many people in the voting ring that I only issued warnings to what appeared to be the ringleaders. Sorry that I didn't warn you as well, I figured your friends would let you know.

Comment: Nice work, particularly that you as mod have no access to induvidual voting data, only to some aggrevated one.